# Fetching data from db and array

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have an API that fetches data from database. My database contains such as this values

ID    Name
1    Body
2    Skin
3    Fat

I have an API that correctly fetches this. I display it on the table but then, the displayed value for example; if the value that is correct is number 1, the name that will be displayed on the UI is "Skin" instead of "Body" what could be the problem?

I have this on my controller

```
Service.fetchType()
            .then(function(data){

                $scope.type= data.data;
                localStorage.Type = JSON.stringify(data.data);
            }
        );
```

And only uses ng-repeat and {{item.Type}} on my html file

```
<tr ng-repeat=" item in Type >
  <td> {{ item.type}}   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: give some code of html and controller... this is because array starts at index 0.. but i need to see wat u hv done

Comment: give $scope.Type and Ng repeat also

Comment: @bleykFaust: Add your data format.

Comment: @MuhammedNeswine what data format?

Comment: @bleykFaust: 'data.data' value

Comment: @MuhammedNeswine its in json format.

Comment: @bleykFaust: May be a typo error but in ng-repeat, the 'Type' is not assigned anywhere in  scope. Did you mean 'type' instead of 'Type' in ng-repeat? And also can u showm me the sample JSON data ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139204/discussion-between-bleykfaust-and-muhammed-neswine).

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have Json string as :  **[{"ID" :1, "Name":"Body" },{"ID" :2, "Name":"Skin" },{"ID" :3, "Name":"Fat" }]** and following works perfect. You can skip last line to convert json string to object.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.type= [{"ID" :1, "Name":"Body" },{"ID" :2, "Name":"Skin" },{"ID" :3, "Name":"Fat" }];  
//$scope.type = angular.fromJson(Json);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="item in type" >
  <td> {{ item.ID}}   </td>
 <td> {{ item.Name}}   </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```